# Compare function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does there exist a built-in function `f(a, b)` in javascript, that would return:

- -1 if a < b
- 0 if a == b
- 1 if a > 1

?

Comment: I think no, but there is a similar behavior with `inArray(), indexOf`

Comment: You could use `Array.prototype.sort`, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: I suppose it's *for* sorting.

Comment: @dystroy, no, **it's not for sorting.** It's geometrical relationships, but it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ledlogic solution inspired me for this one (**works only for numbers**, which is my case now):

```
Math.sign(a - b);
```

The advantage of this is that I don't need to write function for it, unlike the `? :` @doorknob solution, where *I have to* write a function for it unless I want multiple evaluation of expressions `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 6):

No, but it would be quite easy to make:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 especially for the "No" :) This is the obvious solution where you *must* create a function if you don't want the expressions `a` and `b` evaluated multiple times. Now I found more elegant method using `Math.sign()`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler method when it's guaranteed you are dealing with numbers:

```
function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

When dealing with strings, you might want to use localeCompare.

There are more sort examples at [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)